# How can I get a response with the following page in requests?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, webforms

There is a FIPS website with all registered patents. It works like this: a form is filled in, which determines in which databases the search will take place at https://www.fips.ru/iiss/db.xhtml , then after the post request and pressing submit "go to search" it goes to https: / /www.fips.ru/iiss/search.xhtml with a new form and a new submit. Below is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

post_url = 'https://new.fips.ru/iiss/db.xhtml'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(post_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['db-selection-form:dbsGrid1:0:dbsGrid1checkbox'] = 'on'
    payload['db-selection-form:j_idt90'] = 'перейти к поиску'
    r = s.post(post_url,data=payload)
    print(r.text)
```

The problem is that after my actions in the answer, it again returns https://www.fips.ru/iiss/db.xhtml , and not https://www.fips.ru/iiss/search.xhtml , as it happens in the browser. How can I fix this behavior for what I need?

Comment: maybe you should send your post request to the search page and not the db one

Comment: I tried but doesn't work(